# How to fix sitemap got Error details: 1 Errors, 0 Warnings.?

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

I am trying to upload my sitemap to Google webmaster and received 1 error.

How can I fix with this error?

> Error details: 1 Errors, 0 Warnings.
>
> Description:
>
> We encountered an error while trying to access your Sitemap. Please ensure your Sitemap follows our guidelines and can be accessed at the location you provided and then resubmit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sitemap is either configured incorrectly or doesn't exist on the link you've specified. The simplest way to add a sitemap is to use a plugin such as:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/

and then just submit the link to Google http://yoursite.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: Very thanks bro its work for me :)

Comment: but when I am created sitemap already can I uninstall this plugin ?

Comment: Hi. your more than welcome. And you would have to leave the plugin there as it also adds new pages, posts and media to the site map.